# How to create reaction role with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am making a reaction role system, but when I react with the emoji I put, it does nothing. The code is here:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 757982178691776635:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
        if payload.emoji.name == 'white_check_mark':
            print('Role')
```

I get no error in console and it does not print Role in console.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the value of `payload.emoji.name`, it is going to be the emoji itself usually.  If you want to match based on the unicode name, I suggest using [unicodedata.name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the emoji charcter from [here](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%9C%85/) and then compare it.

I made it a little bit shorter for ease of read.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 757982178691776635:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            print('Role')
```